# An audited relation to a non-audited entity failing on db update

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

```
@Entity   
@Audited    
class A extends BasicEntity{    
    @ManyToOne    
    @JoinColumn(name="b_id")    
    @Audited(targetAuditMode=RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)    
    private B b;    
}

@MappedSuperclass    
public abstract class BasicEntity implements Serializable{    
    @Id    
    private String id;    
}

@Entity    
class B extends BasicEntity{
}
```

For the given example insert to db is working fine but update is failing with log:

> Error accessing field [private java.lang.String BasicEntity.id] by
>   reflection for persistent property [B#id] : {id}; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private java.lang.String B.id] by reflection for
>   persistent property [B#id] : {id}

I am using "5.2.10.Final" envers jar

Comment: This sounds very similar to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11859.  Can you upgrade to 5.2.18 in order to see whether or not it continues to be a problem and let me know?

Comment: Thank u for the reply upgrading worked, thanks a lot